# VAADIN/* in web servlet annotation causing error "does not support asynchronous operations exception"

Tags: java, vaadin, tomcat8, vaadin7

This is sort of related to another post of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71229144/3329922), but I have a simpler question here.  I am experiencing weird behavior with the following webservlet annotation: `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, name = "WmsServlet", asyncSupported = false)`.  It works perfectly with `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "WmsServlet", asyncSupported = false)`.  For the `/VAADIN/*` situation, I see the following in my tomcat log.    I don't need to do anything, just load it in browser.  Why?

Here is the exception I get when the page is loaded (tomcat log):

```
[2022-02-24 14:31:36 EST] SEVERE org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [WmsServlet] in context with path [/turnsmithtest] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1686)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1038)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:398)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.startAsync(AtmosphereRequest.java:723)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:93)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:68)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2075)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.handleRequest(PushRequestHandler.java:248)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, it still happens even when I enable asynSupported as follows: `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, name = "WmsServlet", asyncSupported = true)`.  It does not happen when I enable it in this way: `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "WmsServlet", asyncSupported = true)`.

Edit 2/25/2022 to answer comment:
Exception when I use `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, name = "WmsServlet", asyncSupported = true)`:

```
[2022-02-25 12:53:29 EST] SEVERE org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [WmsServlet] in context with path [/turnsmithtest] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1686)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1038)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:398)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.startAsync(AtmosphereRequest.java:723)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:93)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:68)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2075)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.handleRequest(PushRequestHandler.java:248)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the `urlPatterns = {"/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true` case? BTW: there is no need to bind Vaadin to `/VAADIN/*`, this will probably prevent themes and other resources from being loaded.

Comment: I will get the stack trace soon.  BTW, you are right about not needing to bind `/VAADIN/*`, I believe.  When I looked at the deployment documentation for the 20th time, I saw a note saying it only needs to be bound when we are using the Vaadin JAR file, which I am not.  But still curious what causes this error, so will get you the stack trace.

Comment: I might guess that the `CorsFilter` is not defined as asynchronous, but this does not explain why one configuration works and the other doesn't.